# SBS 2008 Sharepoint Database good Memory Limit

Tags: sharepoint, windows-sbs-2008, windows-sbs, backupexec

I manage a small network running on Small Business Server 2008. Lately, the Sharepoint embedded database is getting out of control with its memory usage. I've got a total of 16 GB of RAM on this server, and the Sharepoint database sometimes uses almost 8 GB of RAM. This never happened before, and it started happening after I installed Backup Exec 2010. It happens after a backup is performed. So I suspect there is a memory leak involved. I am working on that issue, but this question isn't about that. I would like to limit the amount of memory the Embedded database uses. I know how to do it. My question is, what would be the ideal amount of memory that I can allocate to Sharepoint? There are only 4 users on my network. One of the users uses two computers but not at the same time. They use sharepoint for a company calendar, and sometimes they share files that way also.

Let me know if you need to know anything else.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

The SQL server will release memory to the OS as necessary. You shouldn't have to configure a limit. If your dead set on limiting the memory, simply pick a number, one random number's as good as any other. Then see how performance is. Adjust as necessary until you fell you've reached a good compromise between RAM usage and performance.

Comment: Just a quick follow up on this "issue." Chris S. You were right. The behavior I thought was a memory leak seems to be the normal behavior. SQL or Exchange in SBS 2011 or 2008 will use as much memory as it wants, and they will release it if something else needs it. So I just left it alone. I didn't change any of the settings. Thanks,